# Spark MLLib 2.0 Categorical Features in pipeline

Tags: java, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to build a decision tree based on log files. Some feature sets are large containing thousands of unique values. I'm trying to use the new idioms of pipeline and data frame in Java. I've built a pipeline with several StringIndexer pipeline stages for each of the categorical feature columns. Then I use a VectorAssembler to create a features vector. The resultant data frame looks perfect to me after the VectorAssembler stage. My pipeline looks approximately like

StringIndexer-> StringIndexer-> StringIndexer->VectorAssembler->DecisionTreeClassifier

However I get the following error:

> DecisionTree requires maxBins (= 32) to be at least as large as the number of values in each categorical feature, but categorical feature 5 has 49 values. Considering remove this and other categorical features with a large number of values, or add more training examples.

I can resolve this issue by using a Normalizer, but then the resultant Decision tree is unusable for my needs, as I need to generate a DSL decision tree with the original feature values. I can't manually set the maxBins because the whole pipeline is executed together. I would like the resultant decision tree to have the StringIndexer generated values (e.g. Feature 5 <= 132). Additionally, but less important, I'd like to be able to specify my own names for the features (e.g. instead of 'Feature 5', say 'domain')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DecisionTree algorithm takes a single maxBins value to decide the number of splits to take. The default value is (=32).  maxBins should be greater or equal to the maximum number of categories for categorical features. Since your feature 5 has 49 different values you need to increase maxBins to 49 or greater.

The DecisionTree algorithm has several hyperparameters, and tuning them to your data can improve accuracy. You can do this tuning using Spark's Cross Validation framework, which automatically tests a grid of hyperparameters and chooses the best.

Here is example in python testing 3 maxBins [49, 52, 55]

```
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(maxDepth=2, labelCol="indexed")
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(dt.maxBins, [49, 52, 55]).addGrid(dt.maxDepth, [4, 6, 8]).addGrid(rf.impurity, ["entropy", "gini"]).build()
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[labelIndexer, typeIndexer, assembler, dt])
```

Comment: Turned out I needed two things: a VectorIndexer with MaxCategories set to a value greater than the count of  the largest number of categorical features, and the DecisionTreeClassifier's maxBins to a value larger than the count of  the largest number of categorical features. Since all my features are categorical I initially specified MAX_INT, which generated a warning "DecisionTreeMetadata: DecisionTree reducing maxBins...". Setting both values to the number of samples in the DataFrame is sufficient.

Comment: As long your features are all categorical, you are safe with VectorIndexer but be careful if your training has continues features. VectorIndexer makes the choice between continuous and categorical is based upon a maxCategories parameter. It can turn continuous feature into categorical.  If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. VectorIndexer was actually a mistake. The pipeline consists of a series of string indexers, followed by a vector assembler, and finally the DecisionTreeClassifier with a .setMaxBins call. As you have correctly pointed out, we'd be in trouble if we had a continuous feature in the mix. I wonder how others handle this? It's easily conceivable to have a categorical feature with a large number of values and a continuous feature with a comparatively smaller number of feature values.

Comment: I think one hot encoder is what you want . Using this you can specify the columns which you want to treat as categorical .

Comment: How do we map the feature number to the original column/feature name?