# Scala - MaxBins error - Decision Tree - Categorical variables

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, decision-tree

My error is similar to these 2 posts , Tried those possibilities but still see the error below :  : 
[CLOUDERA](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/IllegalArgumentException-requirement-failed-maxBins-should-be/td-p/40219)   && [STACK OVERFLOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767786/spark-mllib-2-0-categorical-features-in-pipeline)

```
   var categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int]()
       categoricalFeaturesInfo += (0 -> 31)
       categoricalFeaturesInfo += (1 -> 7)
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: DecisionTree
>   requires maxBins (= 3) to be at least as large as the number of values
>   in each categorical feature, but categorical feature 0 has 31 values.
>   Considering remove this and other categorical features with a large
>   number of values, or add more training examples.

```
   val numClasses = 2
   val impurity = "gini"
   val maxDepth = 9
   val maxBins = 32

val model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses, categoricalFeaturesInfo,impurity, maxDepth, maxBins)
```

Questions :  Largest Categorical variable is 31 , I have tried maxBins = 32 (as per answers in those posts). am I missing anything?

Just as trial n error ,  I tried all set of values like 2 , 3 10 , 15 , 50 , 10000 ,  See same error. !

Map function used :

```
val mlprep = flightsRDD.map(flight => {
  val monthday = flight.dofM.toInt - 1 // category
  val weekday = flight.dofW.toInt - 1 // category
})
```

Comment: What `Map` implementation are you using?

Comment: I am trying to implement this algo using this mapR link. the code is very similar and map function used are same :   https://mapr.com/blog/apache-spark-machine-learning-tutorial/

Comment: updated the post with map function !

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error using PySpark. It could be for many reasons:

1) To make sure `maxBins` is exact, make it equal to the maximum of the quantity of distinct categorical values for each categorical column.

```
maxBins = max(categoricalFeaturesInfo.values() )
```

2) The error message says

> ...but categorical feature 0 has 31 values...

Is column 0 (the very first one, **not** the first feature) of `trainingData` actually the labels of the training set? They must! `DecisionTree.trainClassifier` by default treat the first column as if it were the labels. Be sure labels column is the first one of `trainingData` and not one of the features.

3) How did you get `trainingData` ? 
`DecisionTree.trainClassifier` works for me with table parsed to `LabeledPoint`, just as `RandomForest.trainClassifier`, see http://jarrettmeyer.com/2017/05/04/random-forests-with-pyspark . (*)

4) Also, before transforming the dataset to a LabeledPoint RDD, first transform the original dataframe for indexing the categorical columns.

What works for me is first transforming the source data frame with a `Pipeline`, each stage consisting of a `StringIndexer` transformation for appending another column whose values are the indexed categorical column, and then transform them to a `LabeledPoint`.

**In summary, the way it works for me in PySpark is as follows:**

Suppose the original dataframe is stored in `df` variable and the array of names of its categorical features is stored in `categoricalFeatures` variable-list-array-whateverYouCallIt.

Import `Pipeline` and `StringIndexer` (*):

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
```

To establish the pipeline stages, create an array of `StringIndexer`, each one indexing one categorical column (*). See https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#stringindexer

```
indexers = [ StringIndexer(inputCol=column, outputCol=column) for column in categoricalFeatures ]
```

Be careful here because Spark version 1.6 doesn't have `handleInvalid="keep"` method implemented for `StringIndexer` instances, so you would need to replace `NULL` values after running this stages. See https://weishungchung.com/2017/08/14/stringindexer-transform-fails-when-column-contains-nulls/

Set the pipeline: (*)

```
pipeline = Pipeline( stages=indexers )
```

Now run the transformations:

```
df_r= pipeline.fit(df).transform(df)
```

If there are problems here try changing `outputCol` value for something different in `indexers`. If `NULL` values were present in `df`, a `NullPointerException` would raise.

Now all (categorical) columns in `categoricalFeatures` list are indexed in `df_r`. If you changed some value of `outputCol` when initializing `indexers`, you should remove that original column (whose name is `inputCol` value) from `df_r`.

And finally, declare your `trainingData` using labeled points: (*)

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

trainingData = df_r.rdd.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row[0], Vectors.dense(row[1:])))
```

Here is where all columns of `df_r` must be numeric (thus categorical columns are already transformed to indexed columns) and the label column is the colum number 0 in `df_r`. If not, lets say it is column `i`, change it:

```
trainingData = df_r.rdd.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row[i], Vectors.dense(row[:i]+row[i+1:])))
```

Creating `trainingData` this way works for me.

There is also a fast and easy way to obtain `categoricalFeaturesInfo` from `df_r` metadata: Let `k` be the index of a categorical column transformed with `StringIndexer`,

```
df_r.schema.fields[k].metadata['ml_attr']['vals']
```

stores the original values, you only need to count them all for knowing how many distinct values are in that column number, and also you can recover the original values from there, in stead of using `IndexToString`.

Regards.

(*) *With few changes you can do the same in Scala.*